# Where does QGIS download plugin .zip files prior to install?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I have a QGIS Python plugin we use internally. I've released a new version - edited the "metadata.txt" file, zipped it, replaced the .zip package on our web host, updated our plugins.xml file on the web host, etc.
QGIS sees the updated xml - it shows my plugin as upgradeable. When I upgrade it, it acts like it upgraded, but

a) the bug I just fixed is still there, and

b) the "metadata.txt" file still shows the old info (despite Windows saying all the files were just created).

I've manually deleted the plugin folder (...AppData...python\plugins)
I've manually purged the old .zip from the web host.
I've cleared all copies of the .zip from my Downloads folder.
I've downloaded the new .zip from the host manually, and verified - *yes* the .zip has the new metadata.txt, not the old.
Then I reopen QGIS, install our plugin - it still *somehow* gets the old copy of the code (metadata.txt is back to pre-update, and plugin installer shows it as upgradeable).

If I download the .zip file manually from the web host and then use "install from zip file", it works fine. But I have a dozen or so users, and I'd prefer they get the built-in prompt to update the plugin, rather than me emailing a .zip and forgetting someone.

I'm losing my mind. The only thing I can think of is that wherever the plugin installer downloads the .zip, for some reason the new download isn't overwriting an old download.
So (finally) my question:

**Does anyone know where the QGIS Plugin Installer saves downloaded .zip packages before it unzips them and copies them to the user's plugin folder?**

Comment: I don't know if that will solve your problem, but the answer to your question is just: `QDir.tempPath() + '/' + plugin_zip_filename`. That's where QGIS downloads your plugin ZIP file before unzipping it.